# ArcMap is exporting to extremely large pdf files

Tags: arcgis-9.3, export, pdf

My organization has one user who recently has noticed very large pdf files being exported from her mxds. When I recreate and do the export, I am getting a 4mb file (normal). When she exports the file we are seeing a 2.4 GB file. I changed some settings and was able to get it down to 1GB, but that wasn't satisfactory (obviously).

Things we have recently tried:

-Deleted the normal.mxt (reduced pdf size to 100mb)

-Turned off the setting that saves the spatial information in the pdf

-DPI is at 300

It isn't an overly large mxd. Normal vector data with some labeling. The pdf size is 42" x 60".

Any ideas on what to try next? She is on an ArcEditor 9.3.1 license.

Comment: Have you reviewed this [**ArcGIS Discussion Forum thread**](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?t=258294&f=1731&c=93)?

Comment: PolyGeo'slink is good.  It may not mention one other cause of large pdf file size: the output image quality/resample size.  Set it to normal.  Here's a link to something that might help you find the cause of rasterization: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29935.

Comment: Is it just on this particular machine?  When someone else does the same export on a different machine do they still get a large file?

Comment: just this machine. She sent me the mxd and I exported it at 4mb vs her 2.4 gb. No other users have had this issue.

Comment: Is "compress vectors" turned on in the export options?  Also, try export to PNG and see if that is better.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem where exported PDF would be larger than should be considering the data. In the Export window, I went to the Format tab and changed the Picture Symbol to Vectorize and in the Advance tab I changed the Layers and Attributes drop down to None. Things that used to be in the 50 Megabyte range were now under a Megabyte.

Comment: This worked for me as well and I am using Arc 10.2

Answer (score 1):

Transparency of the layer also affects the size of the PDF considerably. I suggest use transparency to a minimum, or avoid it if you can.